Automatically push a file from the web into Snowflake
I am using an API Get call to get data out of a platform so that I can push it into Snowflake. The API returns the data in a link "https://storage.googleapis.com/...". Is there a way that I can automate the download of this file and upload to Snowflake, or just move it directly to Snowflake without the need to download?
I don't really know where to start with this.

Given the large number of ways of doing this, you really need to narrow down the possibilities by listing the restrictions you are working under (and bear in mind that directly asking for recommendations for tools/software will probably get you question closed)  - but as a starting point, why not write Python code to do this?
